How to make a FAB that bends the Bottom Navigation Bar's Background on Overlay
How can I accomplish the overlay of shopping cart in this photo.

As you can see how does the Shopping Cart Icon bends the background of the Bottom Navigation Bar? Is it part of the Items or a seperate floating action bar that just overlays? I tried to do seperate but the bending is not there. It looks like this,

Here is my navigation code

@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar(navController: NavController) {
    BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .border(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Gray, shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small) // Adding border
            .shadow(elevation = 4.dp, shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small)) {
        val navBackStackEntry by navController.currentBackStackEntryAsState()
        val currentRoute = navBackStackEntry?.destination?.route

        BottomNavItem.values().forEach { item ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                selected = currentRoute == item.route,
                onClick = {
                    navController.navigate(item.route) {
                        popUpTo(navController.graph.startDestinationId)
                        launchSingleTop = true
                    }
                },
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp),
                icon = { Icon(item.icon, contentDescription = null,modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp)) },
                label = { Text(item.label) },
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp))
    }
}

@Composable
fun ShoppingCart() {
    Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize().background(Color.White)) {
        // Main content goes here

        // Floating Action Button
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = { /* Handle click */ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .offset(y = 64.dp)
                .padding(4.dp),
            backgroundColor = Color.hsl(254f,0.44f,0.32f),
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
                contentDescription = "Cart",
                tint = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .padding(24.dp)
                    .size(36.dp))
        }
    }
}



You can achieve this effect by creating a custom shape for the Bottom Navigation Bar.
First, create a custom path for the shape. Here’s the code for it:
fun Path.buildNavPath(
    size: Size,
    fabDiameter: Float,
) {
    val width = size.width
    val height = size.height


    val fabRadius = fabDiameter / 2
    val fabMargin = fabRadius * 0.5f  // Margin around the FAB for the curve

    val r = fabRadius + fabMargin

    val centerX = width - r

    // Move to the start point (top-left corner)
    moveTo(0f, 0f)

    val start = Offset(centerX - r, 0f)
    val center = Offset(centerX, r)
    val end = Offset(width, 0f)

    val c1 = Offset(centerX - fabRadius, 0f)
    val c2 = Offset(centerX - r, r)
    val c3 = Offset(centerX + r, r)
    val c4 = Offset(centerX + fabRadius, 0f)

    lineTo(start.x, start.y)
    cubicTo(
        x1 = c1.x,
        y1 = c1.y,
        x2 = c2.x,
        y2 = c2.y,
        x3 = center.x,
        y3 = center.y
    )
    cubicTo(
        x1 = c3.x,
        y1 = c3.y,
        x2 = c4.x,
        y2 = c4.y,
        x3 = end.x,
        y3 = end.y
    )

    lineTo(width, height)
    lineTo(0f, height)
}

Here’s a visual representation to help understand the path creation:

Next, create a shape using the custom path:
val shape = remember {
     GenericShape { size, _ -> buildNavPath(size = size, fabDiameter = fabSizePx) }
}

Then, wrap your Bottom Navigation Bar in a Surface so you can apply the shape:
Surface(
    shape = shape,
    border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)
) {
    BottomNavigationBar()
}

Finally, tweak the UI to position the Floating Action Button correctly. Here’s the complete code:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            BottomNavAppTheme {

                val fabSize = 60.dp
                val fabSizePx = with(LocalDensity.current) { fabSize.toPx() }

                Scaffold(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    bottomBar = {

                        val shape = remember {
                            GenericShape { size, _ -> buildNavPath(size = size, fabDiameter = fabSizePx) }
                        }
                        Surface(
                            shape = shape,
                            border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)
                        ) {
                            BottomNavigationBar()
                        }
                    },
                    floatingActionButton = { ShoppingCart(fabSize) },
                ) { innerPadding ->
                    Box(modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(innerPadding)
                        .fillMaxSize())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


fun Path.buildNavPath(
    size: Size,
    fabDiameter: Float,
) {
    val width = size.width
    val height = size.height


    val fabRadius = fabDiameter / 2
    val fabMargin = fabRadius * 0.5f  // Margin around the FAB for the curve

    val r = fabRadius + fabMargin

    val centerX = width - r

   + // Move to the start point (top-left corner)
    moveTo(0f, 0f)

    val start = Offset(centerX - r, 0f)
    val center = Offset(centerX, r)
    val end = Offset(width, 0f)

    val c1 = Offset(centerX - fabRadius, 0f)
    val c2 = Offset(centerX - r, r)
    val c3 = Offset(centerX + r, r)
    val c4 = Offset(centerX + fabRadius, 0f)

    lineTo(start.x, start.y)
    cubicTo(
        x1 = c1.x,
        y1 = c1.y,
        x2 = c2.x,
        y2 = c2.y,
        x3 = center.x,
        y3 = center.y
    )
    cubicTo(
        x1 = c3.x,
        y1 = c3.y,
        x2 = c4.x,
        y2 = c4.y,
        x3 = end.x,
        y3 = end.y
    )

    lineTo(width, height)
    lineTo(0f, height)
}

@Composable
fun BottomNavigationBar() {
    BottomNavigation(backgroundColor = Color.White,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .border(
                width = 1.dp,
                color = Color.Gray,
                shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small
            ) // Adding border
            .shadow(elevation = 4.dp, shape = MaterialTheme.shapes.small)) {

        val items = listOf(
            "Home" to Icons.Filled.Home,
            "Search" to Icons.Filled.Search,
            "Profile" to Icons.Filled.Settings
        )

        items.forEachIndexed { index, (label, icon) ->
            BottomNavigationItem(
                selected = false,
                onClick = {},
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = 10.dp, bottom = 10.dp),
                icon = { Icon(icon, contentDescription = null,modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp)) },
                label = { Text(label) }
            )
        }
        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(100.dp))
    }
}

@Composable
fun ShoppingCart(fabSize: Dp) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(Color.White)) {
        // Main content goes here

        // Floating Action Button
        FloatingActionButton(
            onClick = { /* Handle click */ },
            modifier = Modifier
                .align(Alignment.BottomEnd)
                .offset(y = 55.dp),
            backgroundColor = Color.hsl(254f,0.44f,0.32f),
        ) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
                contentDescription = "Cart",
                tint = Color.White,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .size(fabSize)
                    .padding(10.dp)
            )
        }
    }
}

Here’s a demo of the result:

